# Is it possible to remove code comments with Git

Tags: git, minify

Might go against some git best practise, but it possible to remove code comments or minify code with a git command.  Something like `git pull --minify`.

Comment: Git generally doesn't know any programming languages, so you'd have to use an external tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Git must not change code as it goes in or out of the repository *unless* the change is symmetric, that is when you can repeat the transformation in both ways. Typical cases here are end of line transformations (Unix / Mac / Windows). But even that is dangerous (just try this with an image file).

The reason why Git can't do changes like stripping comments: If you made a change to the file, Git would have to remember "I did strip the comments", put the comments back (hoping that this merge wouldn't create additional conflicts) and then commit this result with the repository.

So this would create more places where it can break. Worse, this being a "hidden" part of the process, you would see some very surprising error messages ("??? I didn't write this?? What is Git doing????")

Comment: When you put it like that; sounds as positive as poking a bear with a stick.

Answer (score 3):

Git itself doesn't know how to do anything like this, but Git provides a hooks system, where you can configure Git to invoke some external tool to do that for you. For example you can configure Git pre-commit hook to execute an external tool to minify your JS and CSS files before commiting them to the repo.

Manual: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks